# Do foreign key checks run after a statement or after each modification?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to do a query like

```
WITH tmp (parent_id, child_id, parent_val, child_val) AS (
  VALUES (...)
),
ins_parent AS (
  INSERT INTO parent (parent_id, parent_val)
  SELECT DISTINCT parent_id, parent_val FROM tmp
)
INSERT INTO child (child_id, parent_id, child_val)
SELECT child_id, parent_id, child_val FROM tmp
```

where there's a foreign key from child to parent.

I'm aware that CTEs don't necessarily execute before the main query. What I'm worried about is the server attempting to insert a child row before the corresponding parent row.

I think the question is when FK checks run - do they run after the statement (in which case this should be fine), or after each individual insert (in which case this can potentially throw an error)? I haven't been able to find an answer to that. (I think the FK is NOT DEFERRABLE, because I haven't set that explicitly.)

If it might error, I think it'll be fairly easy to rewrite the query to avoid it. (Probably make `ins_parent` return `parent_id`, and `... child_val FROM tmp JOIN ins_parent USING (parent_id)`.) But I'd rather not make it more complicated than necessary.

Comment: The way you are doing it should be safe. Look at the execution plan, then you know in which order the statement is executed.

Comment: I've checked the query plan, and it looks like it's running the subqueries first, if I'm interpreting correctly. But correct me if I'm wrong, mightn't the query plan change if table statistics change?

Comment: How should the query plan change for a statement like that?

Comment: I don't know, but I wouldn't expect to know. My understanding is that they're not guaranteed to stay the same, and that's about the limit of my knowledge.

In any case, the hint to look at the execution plan put me on track to find the answer I just posted, so thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is safe no matter what order the CTEs execute in. I think that I managed to get them to execute out-of-order, and did not see any FK errors.

I actually have two parent tables, and a query that looks more like

```
WITH tmp (parent1_id, parent2_id, child_id, parents_val, child_val) AS (
  VALUES (...)
),
ins_parent1 AS (
  INSERT INTO parent1 (parent1_id, parents_val)
  SELECT DISTINCT parent1_id, parents_val FROM tmp
)
ins_parent2 AS (
  INSERT INTO parent2 (parent2_id, parents_val)
  SELECT DISTINCT parent2_id, parents_val FROM tmp
)
INSERT INTO child (child_id, parent1_id, parent2_id, child_val)
SELECT child_id, parent1_id, parent2_id, child_val FROM tmp
```

When I check the execution plan (`EXPLAIN WITH tmp ...`), it looks roughly like this:

```
 Insert on child
   CTE tmp
     -> ...
   CTE ins_parent1
     -> ...
   CTE ins_parent2
     -> ...
   -> ...
```

which I think means that all three CTEs will get executed before inserting into `child`.

But I can reorder the query to put `child` inside a CTE, and `parent1` outside:

```
WITH tmp (parent1_id, parent2_id, child_id, parents_val, child_val) AS (
  VALUES (...)
),
ins_child AS (
  INSERT INTO child (child_id, parent1_id, parent2_id, child_val)
  SELECT child_id, parent1_id, parent2_id, child_val FROM tmp
)
ins_parent2 AS (
  INSERT INTO parent2 (parent2_id, parents_val)
  SELECT DISTINCT parent2_id, parents_val FROM tmp
)
INSERT INTO parent1 (parent1_id, parents_val)
SELECT DISTINCT parent1_id, parents_val FROM tmp
```

and the execution plan changes accordingly:

```
 Insert on parent1
   CTE tmp
     -> ...
   CTE ins_child
     -> ...
   CTE ins_parent2
     -> ...
   -> ...
```

so now I think the CTE for `child` gets executed before anything is inserted into `parent1`.

But I still get no FK errors with the query structured like this, which makes me think that any execution order is safe.

Comment: Confirmation hidden in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/ddl-constraints.html: "Restricting and cascading deletes are the two most common options. RESTRICT prevents deletion of a referenced row. NO ACTION means that if any referencing rows still exist when the constraint is checked, an error is raised; this is the default behavior if you do not specify anything. (The essential difference between these two choices is that NO ACTION allows the check to be deferred until later in the transaction, whereas RESTRICT does not.)"